# Help understanding switching voltage regulator (OKR-T/1.5-W12-C)

Tags: dc-dc-converter, switching-regulator

Looks like I need help understanding how to use the OKR-T/1.5-W12-C DC/DC voltage converter, b/c I just burned two of them. I am obviously doing something wrong, but I don't understand what.

Here's the part info:
http://www.digikey.ca/product-search/en?x=-989&y=-73&lang=en&site=ca&KeyWords=811-2782-ND

And here's how I hooked it up:
[image]

The regulator begins heating up rapidly and burns itself out. The first one lasted two days, the second one died in 5 minutes. Turning it on or off with the On/Off pin makes no difference to the heating process. The regulator does supply the expected +Vout until it dies.

P3 is a AA NiMH battery that I am trying to charge.

What am I missing?

**EDIT 1:**
Since the problem is not turning out to be obvious, I think it is time to update this post with complete info. Here's the schematic (I hope you can read that):
[image]

As you can see, I've added the capacitors and a constant current sink. The regulators continue to work for a minute or so and then break to the point where Vout just sits around 1V, not reacting meaningfully to Rtrim anymore. Vout does change when I change Rtrim, but these changes are tiny.

**EDIT 2**:
I'll also add the physical design picture, just in case there are any clues there:
[image]

**EDIT 3**:
I have implemented many of the suggestions provided here with a different buck converter IC, but still no luck! Details here: [Strange oscillation in buck converter (AP3431)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/111897/strange-oscillation-in-buck-converter-ap3431)

Comment: What is your load and how much current does it draw? Does the regulator still heat up with no load connected?

Comment: What kind of battery is P3?  If +Vout=1.5V, minus the diode drop across D2, is higher than the battery voltage, the battery may be drawing a high charging current unless there is some current limiting in the voltage regulator circuit.  Have you measured the current into/out of the battery (in addition to the load, as mentioned above).

Comment: Have you considered putting a replaceable fuse at the input and output?

Comment: Have you looked at the +5V and On/Off pins with an oscilloscope to see if they're pulsing on & off for some reason?

Comment: According to the data sheet (page 16), for +Vout=1.5V, Rtrim (R1 on the schematic) should be 1300 ohms, not 680 ohms. Rtrim of 680 ohms calculates to an output of 2.34V by their equation: Rtrim(kohm) = 1.182/(Vout-0.591).

Comment: The data sheet (page 14) indicates the module requires an external input capacitor of 10 to 22uF ceramic, and output capacitor of 50 to 100uF ceramic, or up to 470uF POSCAP.  These do not appear on your schematic and so may not be in either their module or your circuit.  Without the bulk input & output capacitors a switching regulator could not be expected to regulate properly.

Comment: @Matt_B Yeah, that spec sheet is pretty unclear. Fig 1 Connection diagram doesn't show any required input or output capacitors, while page 14 definitely says they are required. Meanwhile Fig 1 shows just a single capacitor within the board, while the photo shows three. So we are left wondering whether the required caps included or not?

Comment: @MattB.That +1.5V on the schematic is wrong - I forgot to update it after deciding that I need to go with 2.4V, so the resistor is correct. The capacitors though I totally missed. Do the missing caps explain both units getting damaged, after working properly for a period of time?

Comment: @MattB.Also, I did measure the current and it has never exceeded 700mA, which is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @MattB. I did not look at +5V and On/Off pins with an oscilloscope - that didn't occur to me, b/c +5 is connected directly to a USB port, and On/Off is connected to +5, so I don't expect there to be any pulsing.

Comment: Just in case you assumed pin 1 on the device is at the left when looking at the front of the device, it isn't it's on the right hand pin.

Comment: @Andyaka Wow, that pin ordering is awesome. The photo in the datasheet which is captioned "Typical unit" should be revised to show melted epoxy and smoke coming out.

Comment: The pin order is what it is, precisely as shown in the datasheet, which the final user is expected to read. I used to quickly have a look at datasheets too... Now I read them as a fiction book, first to last page.

Comment: A USB-sourced +5V rail is not going to be able to support high current without appropriate resistors on the +D and -D signals. I would check for input sags as well as the previous suggestions of appropriate input and output capacitors.

Comment: @Madmanguruman i don't think this is true if I am using a USB battery pack for my energy source. I just tried it and was able to get 800mA out of the battery pack w/o any resistors on +D and -D

Comment: Details like this really belong in the question.

Comment: Note that you are *supposed* to use resistors to signal the host the amount of current you're drawing, but **many** hosts allow devices to draw much more current. Some USB hosts/chargers will be much more lenient then others.

Comment: Also, the datasheet states: `The minimum external output capacitance required for proper operation 
is 50uF ceramic type.` Considering the general ESR of such an enormous ceramic capacitor, it's likely the device will be **extremely** intolerant of lead-inductance. The long wires you have on your test harness may be enough to produce destructive oscillation. For quick test setups, you will likely have to solder the capacitors **directly** to the device pins.

Comment: @ConnorWolf: I had that thought too, so I tried soldering the last regulator I had and caps on a small piece of protoboard, so the caps were millimetres away. Didn't help.

Comment: I have implemented many of the suggestions provided here, but still no luck. Details here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/111897/strange-oscillation-in-buck-converter-ap3431

Answer (score 2):

If I were you, this is what I would do first:

- Read every page of [the datasheet](http://www.murata-ps.com/data/power/okr-t1-5-w12.pdf).
- Is "pin 1" really what I think it is? The pin numbering on p. 12 of the datasheet runs in the opposite direction from what I expected.
- Do I have every pin connected correctly, according to the input/output connection table on p. 12?
- p. 14 recommends an input capacitor and mentions a "minimum external output capacitance required for proper operation", but neither is shown on the above schematic. Do I have at least the minimum recommended input and output capacitors?
- Directly connect pin 1, the On/Off Control input, to GND or +Vin. The p. 3 of the datasheet mentions "a 49.2 KOhm pulldown to GND", and p. 4 mentions "The On/Off Control input should use either a switch or an open collector/open drain transistor references to -Input Common". The 10 MOhm on the above schematic is outside those guidelines. A 10 MOhm pulldown is weak enough to be easily overcome by exactly the sorts of high-current transient noise that I expect a switching voltage generator to produce.
- Consider looking at each pin with an O'scope -- is it what I expected? (smooth, constant input and output voltages, without any significant transients or pulsing or ringing).

And if all that fails:

- Ask for help, perhaps on Electronics Stackexchange.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed suggestions. I am pretty sure I've got the pinout right (otherwise I would not be getting the voltages I expect), but I will follow all of your other suggestions about caps and resistor and post here after I try it with a new unit.

Comment: The caps made no difference. Read and re-read the datasheet, but still no closer to a solution. Question updated with latest info.

Answer (score 1):

At the very least, you need a resistor between D2 and pin 1 of battery P3, to limit the charging current into the battery.  As it stands, the battery can draw as much current as the regulator is capable of putting out.  Besides being probably way more than you want, it isn't even a known quantity.  It will be limited somewhere between the regulator's overcurrent protection and the maximum the battery can sink.  It's similar to putting nearly a dead short on the output of the regulator, in parallel with whatever the intended load is, where the wire goes off the top of the schematic near the battery.

If the module does in fact need input & output capacitors as mentioned on page 14 of the data sheet (and comments above), as it stands you are to some extent using the battery as an output capacitor.  You're using the output capacitor of the 5V regulator in the USB device as your input capacitor, but then probably some long wire leading to this circuit, which adds resistance and inductance.  So it's possible the regulator could produce the required output but would not be stable under variation in the load.  It's not clear whether the module has these capacitors on it or not, as ceramic capacitors wouldn't be all that big and might be the larger brown ones between the inductor and the pins.  It wouldn't hurt to add more, up to some level, so maybe add some at the low end of the recommended range, 10uF input and 50uF output, in case they'll be in parallel with any that are on the board already.

You have no battery charge termination, meaning no circuit to turn off charging when the battery is full.  If you intend a continuous trickle charge and/or you'll disconnect the battery manually after a reasonable time, or don't care if the battery gets badly overcharged and ruined, maybe the current-limiting resistor would be enough.  If you're trying to charge the battery at all quickly (a few hours or less), you need a better charger circuit.

I asked about putting a scope on +5V and the On/Off pins in comments because it's possible they are oscillating for some reason, triggering the regulator to have to ramp up & down over and over, where it might look like the output is being regulated but the circuit isn't working as expected.  +5V could sag or oscillate if it's being overloaded (as Madmanguruman mentions), On/Off pin could oscillate because R6 is too high a value (as davidcary mentions).

To start with, you could take D2 out of the circuit so the regulator has neither the battery nor load on its output, and scope every pin you can touch to see if things look as you expect, and stable.  Then put say a 10W power resistor (calculate the value so it draws similar current as your actual load) between the regulator output and ground and scope things to see if they still look good.  This tests the regulator unloaded and fully loaded.  You could add tests for half load, pulsed load, etc. if you don't trust the regulator or want to understand its behavior better.

Once you believe the regulator can do its job, then try connecting the actual load and not the battery.  Maybe first add a fuse between the regulator and load just in case.  If the regulator can run the load properly with the battery out of the circuit, then try adding back the battery, with current-limit resistor.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, Matt. Since I broke all 3 of my regulators now, I have to wait until I get more to try your incremental troubleshooting suggestions. In the mean time, I'll update the original post with all of the current information about the circuit.

Comment: OK, hope it helps.  In the added schematic, can you explain what IC2 is and does?  It's hard to read.  Also, in the photo, what is taped onto the battery, is it a thermistor for charging?  Is that on the schematic?

Comment: In my answer above, I assumed P3 connected to battery + on pin 1 and battery - on pin 2, which does not seem to be the case.  I can't read the new schematic well enough to find P3 but maybe the other side of P3 also includes IC2 and not just the battery cell?

Comment: IC2 is an Arduino. A 1-Wire temperature sensor is taped to the battery. It is marked in the schematic as K3. The new schematic is actually a very high res image - I don't know why stackexchange is not letting you click on it. If you get the URL to it and open in another tab, you'll be able to see a lot of detail.