# Troubleshooting a SEPIC regulator (MIC2296)

Tags: dc-dc-converter, boost, sepic

I am trying to regulate a 5V input, which drops to around 3.5V when a large load is applied. I need to keep the 5V steady, and I am willing to do this at the expense of current, which is why I thought that using a boost regulator is appropriate here.

Since my input voltage can be slightly above 5V when the load is small, and under 5V when the load is large, I think I need to use a [SEPIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-ended_primary-inductor_converter) regulator. The [datasheet](http://www.micrel.com/_PDF/mic2296.pdf) for MIC2296 says that it can be used in this way, although it does not provide a sample schematic.

Here's what I have so far:
[image]

[image]

There are two problems with it.

1. It is unstable. A correct voltage is provided for the first minute or so (although it oscillates by ~200mV even during this period). The voltage at "FB" pin hovers around 1.2V (shouldn't it be @Vref, which is 1.24V?). After a minute the output voltage suddenly spikes and goes up to ~9V. Voltage at "FB" drops to ~0.9V. At this point I have to disconnect power, since my load resistor can't handle too much current.
2. If I power on my actual circuit with this regulator and then activate the current hungry load, the regulator fails to keep the voltage at 5V and allows it to drop to < 4V, so the regulator is not doing its job of trading current for voltage. Why?

The load in the circuit will switch between a light load (~50mA) and a heavy load. The heavy load will be anywhere between 500mA and 800mA, depending on what my battery pack can provide at 5V.

What can I do troubleshoot these problems?

Comment: You seem surprised.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Why shouldn't I be surprised? The circuit is not working in accordance with my current understanding of the subject. Obviously my understanding is lacking, but this is why I would appreciate your help.

Comment: You can only trade current for voltage if you aren't actually using all the current available from the supply.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Oh I see what you mean. I don't think that in this case the problem was that the battery was tapped out. I just did an experiment using a 5V wall adapter instead of the battery. Vout was 5V, with a test load resistor drawing 45mA. I then hooked up a parallel resistor that should have taken the current to 147mA. Obviously this is well withing the capabilities of a wall power adapter. What I observed was that the Vout first fell to 2.9V, then went back up to 5V, and finally increased to 9V, where I had to quickly unplug it. So it's back to the instability problem.

Comment: Can you tell why you have used C1 and L2 in your circuit? None of the sample circuits provided in the datasheet is using them.

Comment: @Alvin: C1 and L2 are part of the standard SEPIC configuration. C1 is a coupling capacitor that DC isolates the input and output. L2 is what allows us to use this boost regulator in a situation when Vin is larger than Vout. This is described in the link I provided. I got the idea of doing this from ADP1613 and LT3460 datasheet. Both of these show the circuit.

Comment: Just a small thought though, you have mentioned that the FB pin voltage initially hovers around 1.2V instead of 1.24V. Is the tolerances of resistors R1 and R2 keeping it below the required value? From the snap, it looks like you are using 5% tolerance resistors.

Comment: @Alvin: This is true, but incorrect resistor values would result in slightly different Vout, rather than this completely erratic behaviour, would they not?

Comment: @ValBlant From all of your other posts and seeing your original schematic, you should have no need for any kind of boost or sepic converter at this stage. You already have a buck converter for the battery itself 5V -> 1.8V. Have you tried getting the buck/battery charger to work on its own without all the arduino stuff? I also noticed on your main schematic that you have a huge 980 ohm feedback resistor when the data sheet says to use only 0.2 Ohm resistor. I think you need to start at the endpoints and work your way back up.

Comment: @horta: Good catch about the 980ohm resistor - that's an error in my schematic which I'll need to correct. The real resistor is around 0.2ohms though. I'll definitely try your suggestion of starting with just the battery charger and slowly adding the Arduino stuff. Just have to wait for parts for a couple of days. I am not sure why I wouldn't need the specic converter though. How will my 5V to 1.8V buck prevent the voltage to the Arduino from dropping once I start drawing lots of current?

Comment: Not sure about the 9 volt instability. But you might be able to improve stability under load using larger values in the feedback divider. Loading the circuit can draw current away from the feedback pin and make voltage sag unnecessarily. Just had this problem myself. Reviewing drawings for large output designs, i found they avoid the feedback divider problem using opto isolators. I also saw one converter with an inverting output whose feedback divider was run from the negative output voltage back to a regulated +5 volt reference, and so didn't have a parallel path with the load.

Comment: @ValBlant It won't specifically prevent your voltage droop. You can think of your circuit as the water lines in a house. If you open all of the faucets, the water not only loses pressure (voltage) but also flow (current). Since you're out of flow and pressure, you have two choices, either limit the amount of faucets open (limit the current of the charging circuit more) or increase the amount of water your source can provide (double up power supplies or batteries). You may also have a short (or transient short) in your charging circuit. Test your charging circuit first alone.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to trouble shoot these types of situations remotely. Let's start with your two problems, and see what can be said about them.

1. *"It is Unstable"*  Well, maybe not.

   - The 200mV on the output could just be ripple. Given the amount of ripple current, and enough ESR in \$C_{\text{out}}\$, that would be a reasonable amount of ripple. If the 200mV is at 600kHz, then it's ripple not oscillation.
   - \$V_{\text{FB}}\$ dropping from ~1.2V to ~0.9V would cause \$V_{\text{out}}\$ to shoot up (I'm actually surprised it doesn't go up more than that). The regulator would be reacting to raise \$V_{\text{FB}}\$ back to 1.2V. The only reason \$V_{\text{FB}}\$ stays at 1.2V is due to feedback and regulation. Also, you don't get to observe \$V_{\text{ref}}\$, it has to be inferred from \$V_{\text{FB}}\$. That this happens after "a minute or so" suggests that it is a thermal thing not an electronic thing. It is as though \$R_1\$ loses proper connection and that allows \$R_2\$ to pull \$V_{\text{FB}}\$ low. These peg type breadboards, with use, can get the contacts deformed so connections get intermittent or thermally sensitive. Do any of the parts get hot (especially \$\text{IC}_1\$, \$C_{\text{out}}\$, or \$D_1\$), and what happens if \$R_1\$ is removed?
2. At higher loads *"regulator fails to keep the voltage at 5V and allows it to drop to < 4V"* ... *"Why?"* There are a bunch of possible causes.

   - First, switching power supplies convert power. If the supply were perfect \$P_{\text{out}}\$ would equal \$P_{\text{in}}\$. That means that for a constant load, if \$V_{\text{in}}\$ went down, \$I_{\text{in}}\$ would have to go up a corresponding amount. So, the input of a switching supply looks like a negative resistance (or impedance). If the source output resistance is not less than the supply input resistance, at the least the source voltage will be pulled down and commonly will oscillate.
   - There are all kind of possible problems with breadboards. Things like parasitic resistances and inductances (in the board and in the components) can have a big impact on SMPS operation. For example, the breakout board that \$\text{IC}_1\$ is mounted on could be a problem both thermally and inductively. MIC2296 needs an amount of copper pad to get rid of heat properly (usually specified on the datasheet, although I didn't see it).

---

**Some things to expect from this regulator**

For a SEPIC, output voltage to input voltage can be related as:

M = \$\frac{V_{\text{out}}}{V_{\text{in}}}\$ = \$\frac{D}{1-D}\$ where \$\ D\$ is duty cycle (in constant conduction mode)

also, \$\ D\$ = \$\frac{V_{\text{out}}}{V_{\text{in}}+V_{\text{out}}}\$

If \$V_{\text{in}}\$ = \$V_{\text{out}}\$, then \$\ D\$ will be 0.5.  This gives an easy way to calculate the current for boundary conduction mode (BCM, where operation goes from CCM to DCM). Just calculate peak to peak ripple current in \$L_1\$ when \$V_{\text{in}}\$ is 5V and BCM current will be half that.

\$i_{L-\text{ppk}}\$ = \$\frac{D V_{\text{in}} T_s}{L}\$ ~ 400mA

So, with \$L_1\$ = 10uH, the boundary for continuous conduction will be \$I_{\text{in}}\$~200mA. Usually best to choose CCM or DCM since the loop dynamics are different. CCM dynamics are more complicated (2 poles +2 poles in a SEPIC), but if compensated for CCM will stay stable for DCM (just not optimal in DCM). An advantage of CCM is that peak currents are lower in the switch and inductors, and output ripple voltage is lower. If you want CCM down to 50mA, L will need to be about 40uH.

Average \$I_{\text{in}}\$ and \$I_{\text{out}}\$ are related as:

\$I_{\text{in}}\$ = \$\frac{D I_{\text{out}}}{1-D}\$

To get peak input current just add half the inductor ripple current.

Peak switch current would be \$I_{\text{in}}\$+\$I_{\text{out}}\$+\$i_{L-\text{ppk}}\$ since the switch sees the current of both inductors. MIC2296 has a max switch current of 1.2A (chip will limit current there).

And that's kind of tough, since at \$V_{\text{in}}\$ of 3V (and D of 0.625), \$I_{\text{out}}\$ will be limited to ~ 300mA.

Some good references for SEPIC are [SLYT309](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt309/slyt309.pdf) and [SLUA158](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slua158/slua158.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify clearly how large the load is in your application.

Trying to get a high frequency DCDC to work on a experiment board is not easy. Stray capacitances, no ground plane and god knows what.

For a SEPIC you could have a look at the [LT3460 datasheet](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/34601fb.pdf), at the last page is a schematic with component values.

A simple approach could be to use a linear regulator to keep the voltage below 5V and a step up regulator in front of it. You will loose efficiency of course. And the power loss might be too high for your application.

Comment: The large load will be anywhere between 500mA and 800mA, depending on what my battery pack can provide at 5V. Efficiency is crucial here, since the whole thing is a solar panel project.

Comment: @ValBlant What is your load though? We need to understand  what kind of load you have so that we can understand whether it's linear or non-linear in nature.

Comment: It's worth pointing out to the op that the LT3460 isn't suitable for his application - it hasn't got the amperage capabilities.

Comment: @horta: The load is a circuit with an Arduino Mini, an LCD screen, and then another buck converter down to 1.8V, which is used to charge a AA NiMH battery via a constant current sink (an LED Driver chip).